# What is the energy difference between inner subshells?

Tags: energy, electrons, orbitals, electronic-configuration, atoms

For exemple, in silver the energy difference between the 4d 5s subshells is ≈ 4 eV (in the ultraviolet region, that's why it has no color, etc.), but what is the energy difference between some of its inner subshells, like 4s 3d, 3d 4p or 4s 4p?

I assume there is also a energy difference between them, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To find the energy difference between any of the subshells you can use the equation for Rydberg's formuals : Delta (E)= -2.17*10^-18J (1/nf^2)-(1/ni^2)